# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-safe-area-context:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug'

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I install react-navigation library for react-native.Install dependencies then i got this error.

```
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-safe-area-context:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not create task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin'.
      > No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.PropertiesProvider.JvmTargetValidationMode.WARN�NG

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 16s
error Failed to install the app.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.7",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0"
  },
```

I follow react-navigate documentation and i got error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're facing a build issue related to Kotlin in your React Native project. First, run `react-native doctor` to check and fix any environment problems. If the issue persists, make sure your `android/build.gradle` file has a compatible Kotlin version. You can try cleaning the project by running `cd android && ./gradlew clean`. If needed, check the library's GitHub for any reported solutions or seek advice from the community. Don't forget to back up your project before making changes!

Comment: I can start react-native doctor and i give 2 errors.Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0 and ✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.I search the problem i can found they tell me to download android sdk command line tools Package "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)" (cmdline-tools;latest) should be installed in it already exists.

Comment: It seems there's a compatibility issue with your React Navigation and Kotlin versions. Try updating your React Navigation packages to the latest version compatible with your React Native version. Also, check if there are any specific Kotlin version requirements in the React Navigation documentation and adjust your project settings accordingly. Running `react-native doctor` and checking for any suggested fixes might help as well.

Comment: did my last comment helped anyone ? if it did do let me know thanks you.

Comment: i just came back to know if i helped anyone if i did do let me know and feel free to ask more

Comment: Hello https://stickwarapk.download/